# Arch Linux resolving issues

Tags: arch-linux, dns, raspberry-pi, systemd-resolved

I have a Rasberry Pi running Arch and i'm encountering some weird resolving behavior. Long story short, `dig` and `nslookup` can resolve hostnames, `curl`, `wget`, `pacman` can't. If i add a host in `/etc/hosts` everything works fine for that host.

Here is the output of some troubleshooting:

1. `resolv.conf` exists and is readable:

   ```
   $ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Apr 28 10:45 /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. I have a nameserver:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```
3. `nslookup` works:

   ```
   $ nslookup google.com
   Server:         8.8.8.8
   Address:        8.8.8.8#53

   Non-authoritative answer:
   Name:   google.com
   Address: 92.87.11.30
   Name:   google.com
   Address: 92.87.11.54
   Name:   google.com
   Address: 92.87.11.49
   Name:   google.com
   Address: 92.87.11.45
   ...
   ```
4. `dig` works:

   ```
   $ dig google.com

   ; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P3 <<>> google.com
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20686
   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

   ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;google.com.                    IN      A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.49
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.50
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.48
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.44
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.42
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.41
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.51
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.36
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.39
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.45
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.37
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.40
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.38
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.47
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.43
   google.com.             299     IN      A       92.87.175.46

   ;; Query time: 40 msec
   ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
   ;; WHEN: Fri Apr 28 11:37:32 EEST 2017
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 295
   ```
5. I can `ping` one of the IPs:

   ```
   $ ping 92.87.175.49
   PING 92.87.175.49 (92.87.175.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 92.87.175.49: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=3.75 ms
   64 bytes from 92.87.175.49: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=3.71 ms

   --- 92.87.175.49 ping statistics ---
   2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.711/3.734/3.758/0.065 ms
   ```
6. `wget` fails:

   ```
   $ wget https://google.com
   --2017-04-28 11:39:31--  https://google.com/
   Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
   Resolving google.com... failed: Name or service not known.
   wget: unable to resolve host address 'google.com'
   ```
7. `curl` fails:

   ```
   $ curl https://google.com
   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
   ```

What am I missing?!...

Edit:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost

# End of file

$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# Begin /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: compat mymachines systemd
group: compat mymachines systemd
shadow: compat

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files

# End /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

It seems it has something to do with `systemd-resolvd`. If i stop it or remove `resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, resolving works fine for every app, if i start it again or leave `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as is, resolving works only for `nslookup` & `dig`.

Comment: Does your network require you to use a HTTP proxy?

Comment: @tripleee No proxy i required.

Comment: Can you `nc 92.87.175.49 80`?  What about `openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect 92.87.175.49:443`?

Comment: You could try running `strace wget https://google.com` to see what the wget program does and where the name lookup goes wrong. The contents of `/etc/host.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` could also be of interest.

Comment: @JohanMyréen both files can be used for workarounds (adding hosts in `/etc/hosts/` or removing `resolve` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`), but why `dig` and `nslookup` work while other apps don't...

Comment: I don't know. That's why I suggested you run strace on the wget program, to see if the listing would give a clue to what goes wrong. You could also try some other addresses, with and without https, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: (@JohanMyréen) The specific programs `host nslookup dig` are part of the BIND package and ONLY use the DNS server (defaulted or specified), not the full name-resolution logic (typically in libc) used by most programs. Your DNS server (8.8.8.8) is fine and it's something else in name-resolution that's bad, apparently whatever nsswitch setting `resolve` invokes.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so basically `host`, `nslookup` and `dig` are ignoring `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  That means the problem, in my case, is `systemd-resolvd`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem after archlinuxarm updates: some sites works but most of them are unavailable and pacman cannot updates. In my case the problem is dnssec on system resolver. It may be detected by runing from console:

resolvectl query archlinuxarm.org 
(or any other unavailable site)

the answer was:
... DNSSEC validation failed: invalid

In my case helped addition DNSSEC=false to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
and reboot

Comment: This happened to me too just recently, also on archlinuxarm. However, I got `archlinuxarm.org: resolve call failed: DNSSEC validation failed: signature-expired` as a result of the command. But adding `DNSSEC=false` still fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I also had this on a pi but adding `DNSSEC=false` didn't help. Deleting `resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf` did.